# C++ OpenGL how to get rotations x,y,z from quaterion

Tags: c++, opengl, quaternions

I have been handling object rotations in my engine by storing object`s x,y and z rotation and then when I am about to render, I was creating the transformation matrix like this.

```
    // entity.getRotation() returns a glm::vec3 where I use these
    //values to rotate the object.

    glm::mat4 model;
    model = glm::translate(model, entity.getPosition());
    model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(entity.getRotation().x), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(entity.getRotation().y), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(entity.getRotation().z), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(entity.getScale(), entity.getScale(), entity.getScale()));
```

Now, I implemented an AntTweakBar GUI into my engine where there is an option to be able to rotate objects on the GUI. I am currently trying to make it possible to rotate the objects in GUI and see the resulting rotations in the engine. The problem is that GUI works with quaternions while in my engine object rotation is stored as 3 floats of x,y,z rotation amounts.

My question is, how can I take the quaternion and turn it into x, y, z rotations so that I can use my above mention method to create the transformation matrix?

I found this method in glm

```
glm::eulerAngles(glm::quat(q[0], q[1], q[2], q[3]));
```

but upon looking at returned vec3, it does not seem like what I am looking for. I believe eulerAngles returns pitch, yaw, and roll which behaves incorrectly when I try to use these values to create my Transformation matrix.

Edit:
I found my mistake. It turned out that my old solution was fine(Although as someone pointed out in comments using quats might be faster). The problem was in my conversion from float array representation of quat(float array representation for AntTweakBar) to angles. It seems like AntTweakBar stores the x,y,z,w components in quat in a different order in the float array. The correct order in the float array is y,z,w,x but I have no clue why this is.

Comment: I would just switch the engine to be able to work with quaternions. (What you're trying to do would be inefficient, since directly making a matrix from a quaternion doesn't use any trig functions.)

Comment: I actually realized that and I am currently working on it but I was really curious how can I achieve this without changing to quaternions.

Comment: Also, if I switch the engine to work with quaternions and I want to rotate something by some degree on some of the axes for example, wouldn't I face the same problem of converting degrees to quaternions ?

Comment: Degrees to quaternions is easy, you just combine rotations in a way similar to what you do with matrices.

Comment: I see. Also, I just tried to use quaternions instead of rotations by doing this

glm::mat4 model;
model = glm::translate(model, entity.getPosition());
glm::mat4 RotationMatrix = glm::toMat4(quat);
model = model  *RotationMatrix;
model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(entity.getScale(), entity.getScale(), entity.getScale()));
shader->setMat4("model", model);

but it seems like axises are reversed. I mean rotations work as expected but it seems like everything is multiplied by 180 degrees. Is this a problem in a way that I create my transformation matrix?

Comment: I'm not sure. Try transposing the matrix you get from the quaternion.

Comment: Hmm did not work. It seems like everything is flipped around XZ plane. Well, it`s time to start doing some debugging I guess.

Comment: When using the `glm::eulerAngles()` function are you expecting the angles to be in degrees or radians?

Comment: @FrancisCugler I did the correct conversion from radians to degrees before using. I actually found my mistake. For some reason that I dont understand yet, when converting the float array representation of quat(AntTweakBar uses float array) to glm::quat, I was doing glm::quat q = glm::quat{quatArray[0], quatArray[1], quatArray[2], quatArray[3]}. It turned out that I had to do glm::quat q = glm::quat{quatArray[4], quatArray[0], quatArray[1], quatArray[2]} for some reason. I guess AntTweakBar represents their quats like that ?

Comment: @Saik that could be possible, I'm not familiar with AntTweakBar, but I am with GLM to a degree.

Comment: There is a 12 ways to apply euler anges. Be sure that you are using proper one. 

I mean XYZ, ZYX , ZXZ and more.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles

Answer (score 2):

With GLM there are a couple of options, one that you have already mentioned, however make sure that your measure of angles are consistent. If you are using and relying on `radians` most of `GLM's` library methods past a specific version now expects all angles that are being passed into their rotation functions in `radians` however according to their docs when working with quaternions and using `glm::eulerAngles()`; it returns the angles `pitch as X`, `yaw as Y`, and `roll as Z` in degrees unless `GLM_FORCE_RADIANS` is defined.

Another alternative would be to use these two methods:

- *`glm::mat4_cast`*

  > ```
  > GLM_FUNC_DECL tmat4x4<T, P> glm::mat4_cast  ( tquat< T, P > const &  x )
  > ```
  >
  > Converts a quaternion to a 4 * 4 matrix.
  >
  > See also `GLM_GTC_quaternion`  Referenced by `glm::toMat4()`.
- *`glm::quat_cast`*

  > ```
  > GLM_FUNC_DECL tquat<T, P> glm::quat_cast  ( tmat4x4< T, P > const &  x )
  > ```
  >
  > Converts a 4 * 4 matrix to a quaternion.
  >
  > See also `GLM_GTC_quaternion`

If your GUI is using Quaternions you can retrieve that information and save it to a `glm::quaternion` then from there you can use one of these functions to convert it over to a 4x4 matrix. There are also `3x3 matrix-quat` & `quat-3x3 matrix` versions of these conversion functions.